# PHP exec ImageMagick always returns 0

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, imagick

I'm trying to get ImageMagick to count the amount of pages in a PDF file for me. The function is as follows:

```
<?php
function countPdfPages($filepath)
{
    $magick = "identify -format %n ".$filepath;
    exec($magick, $debug, $result);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

However, that function always returns `0`. I have verified that ImageMagick is running properly, so that shouldn't be a problem. Am I not using `exec()` properly? Should I retrieve the output in another way? I've also tried using `$debug`, but that didn't give me any output, oddly.

I bet I'm doing something stupid here, but I just don't see it. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), `exec` provides the *return status* of the executed command via the third argument.  A value of `0` means that it exited normally.  It sounds like you should be using something like [`popen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).

Here's an example lifted from Example #3 of the [`fread` man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) (edited to use `popen`):

```
<?php
// For PHP 5 and up
$handle = popen("identify -format %n myfile.jpg", "r");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
pclose($handle);
// $contents is the output of the 'identify' process
?>
```

Comment: Pff, duh. Overlooked something minor again, thanks! But then, to be honest, I haven't the foggiest as to how I can get the value returned by ImageMagick using that. Think you could help me a bit further here? Thank you so much!

Comment: You'd want something like Example #3 on that man page.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Odd... when I call it and have it `return $contents;`, nothing is returned. No value, no error, nothing. (And yes, I am running PHP5.)

Comment: Two things to try: use a mode of "r" (instead of "rb"), and `pclose` instead of `fclose`.

Comment: More things to try: add `2>&1` to end of command line (in case `identify` is outputting to stderr); substitute a process that outputs 10k+ bytes to stdout (to determine whether it's a buffering issue); turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` as in example #2 of `popen` man page.

Comment: Adding `2>&1` didn't help.
No errors were reported.
Using the dummy process "`echo hello world`" did produce a result, namely `$content` being "`hello world`". So it's a buffering issue, then? (Pfff, this really is not my field. I should dig into this stuff way deeper.)

Comment: Oh oh oh oh, this is really embarrassing! Turns out I had the wrong filepath put into the function, so there was no file for it to go on. Still odd that it didn't present me with _any_ error message, but it's solved and working properly now. Apologies for dragging this out so long, and thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: @Fang I'm glad you figured it out!